# Adding a terminating ";" or "+" in package.json script?

Tags: npm, terminal, package.json

I'm trying to write a script inside my **package.json** that renames every single folder of a certain name (OLD_NAME) within the root direction to something new (NEW_NAME).

If I terminal **cd ...** to the parent directory and type the contents of the below "rename" script, that works. But, if I try to write it in a package.json file...

```
"scripts": {
    "rename": "find . -depth -type d -name 'OLD_NAME*' -execdir mv {} NEW_NAME \;"
}
```

Not only does eslint / prettier get rid of the backslash...

```
    "rename": "find . -depth -type d -name 'OLD_NAME*' -execdir mv {} NEW_NAME ;"
```

...but I get the following terminal error

> find: -execdir: no terminating ";" or "+"

I have tried the following, but to no avail

```
    "rename": "find . -depth -type d -name 'OLD_NAME*' -execdir mv {} NEW_NAME /\\;"
```

I am unable to search using the right question to get an answer, or figure this out. Any suggestions?

Comment: what does that have to do with a terminating semicolon error?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and solved it using `\\;` instead of `\;` or `;` or `/\\;`

Sample code is below

`"find packages -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'cd {} && ncu -u' \\;"`